# How can I find stuff in the pantry?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

So I'm lighting the signal fires for the highland lord. In order to 'beat' Twin Peak, I need to search the pantry, however when I do I fail. A little research on the wiki suggests I need an Item Drop boost of +50%. This seems insane, with all my current gear I can only get 10%. Where can I, as a level 9 Sauceror, get gear/effects to boost my Item Drop to 50%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the main things to note about this requirement is that it counts *Food* drops, not just Item drops. Therefore the easiest way to do this is to get an increase to your Food drop rate, which is generally easier than the regular Item Boost Drop.

Increased booze drop rates, do *not* count towards this total and neither do Fairy-type familiars. However, familiar *equipment* with increased Item drop rate (like the [Chiptune Guitar](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Chiptune_guitar)), *will* count.

[This](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Maximizing_Your_Item_Drops) page on the official Wiki has several options for increasing your drop rate, but here are some of the easiest for this purpose:

### Quests

- Complete the [Deep Fat Friars' Gate Quest](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Deep_Fat_Friars%27_Gate_Quest) in the [Copse of the Deep Fat Friars](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Copse_of_the_Deep_Fat_Friars). This quest has a minimum requirement of level 6 and you will receive it from the Council of Loathing.

  - After completing it, you will be eligible to receive buffs from the friars. Get [Brother Flying Burrito's Blessing](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Brother_Flying_Burrito%27s_Blessing) from Brother Flying Burrito, the Deep Fat Friar, as it's one of the easiest food boosts to get. It gives you a whopping **+30% to Food Drops from Monsters**, which will last 20 adventures.

To make up the last 20%, you can use either equipment or buffs from various sources. This will partially depend on how much Meat you have to spend in the [Mall](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Mall) and what kind of gear you currently have access to.

### Gear

This is all gear that you should have access to at this point from quests from the Council or from guild quests:

- [Baron Von Ratsworth's Monocle](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Baron_Von_Ratsworth%27s_monocle): **+10% Item Drops from Monsters** (found in the [Tavern Cellar](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Tavern_Cellar) via the [If it's Tiny, is it Still a Mansion?](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/If_it%27s_Tiny,_is_it_Still_a_Mansion%3F) encounter)
- [Miner's Helmet](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Miner%27s_helmet): **+5% Item Drops from Monsters** (quest requirement: [Dwarven Factory Quest](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Dwarven_Factory_Quest))
- [Observational Glasses](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Observational_glasses): **+5% Item Drops from Monsters** (dropped from [Larry of the Field of Signs](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Larry_of_the_Field_of_Signs) in [The Laugh Floor](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/The_Laugh_Floor)).
- [Knob Goblin Eye Drops](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Knob_Goblin_eyedrops) (10 adventures): **+15% Item Drops from Monsters** (purchased in [The Knob Dispensary](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/The_Knob_Dispensary))
- [Cyclops Eyedrops](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Cyclops_eyedrops) (10 adventures): **+100% Item Drops from Monsters** (drops in [the Limerick Dungeon](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/The_Limerick_Dungeon))

If you haven't done the above quests already and/or don't have those items, these are quick and (fairly) cheap Booze/Food options. Obviously prices and availability may vary on the Mall:

- [Honey-Dew](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Honey-dew) gives you the [Mmmmmelon](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Mmmmmelon) effect, which is **+30%** Item Drops from Monsters (10 adventures).
- [Crystal Skeleton Vodka](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Crystal_skeleton_vodka) will give you [Akryophobia](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Aykrophobia), which includes **+25%** Item Drops from Monsters (20 adventures).

Comment: I used a rice bowl.  Pretty cheap at the mall, and they provide the +20% you need all by themselves: http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Rice_bowl

Answer (score 1):

There are a few tricks you can do here.  The first is to know that the needed item drop also includes food bonuses,

This means that getting [Brother Flying Burrito's Blessing](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Brother_Flying_Burrito%27s_Blessing) from the level 6 quest is a huge bonus here as its +30% food drops.

After that, its a matter of [stacking enough](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Items_from_Monsters) for the last 20% ([knob goblin eye drops](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Knob_Goblin_eyedrops) are pretty easy to get).

Also, if you are aware of your [semi-rare](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Semi-rare) count, you can go for a [cyclops eyedrops](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Cyclops_eyedrops) for an instant +100% item find for 10 turns.  This item is also super useful for the filth worms later on.